# Creating Pentaho CDE dashboard with 100% width

Tags: pentaho, pentaho-cde

What is the a best/correct way to create a Pentaho Dashboard (CDE) that uses full width (100%) of a browser window size? I need to remove the default 960 pixel width that screen.css defines.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

1. Use `bootstrap` **dashboard type** instead of default `blueprint`. The dashboard type can be changed in `Settings > Dashboard Type` in CDE editor.
2. If you want to use **full width** you need to override default CSS definition of `container div`. The default value comes from `biserver-ce/pentaho-solutions/system/pentaho-cdf/css/cdf-bootstrap-style-includes.css`.

   ```
   .container {
       width: 1170px;
   }
   ```

   To **override the CSS** navigate to `Add Resource` in a dashboard `Layout` definition and add `CSS Code Snippet` with following code:

   ```
   .container {
       width: auto;
   }
   ```